# Assigning to the pointer which is a member of the struct causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, c99

My goal is to modify [vcprompt](http://bitbucket.org/gward/vcprompt) in such a way that it takes additional param which specifies explicitly for which VCS to show the state. Here's the gist of the changes:

```
typedef struct {
    int debug;
    char *format;                       /* e.g. "[%b%u%m]" */
    int show_branch;                    /* show current branch? */
    int show_revision;                  /* show current revision? */
    int show_patch;                     /* show patch name? */
    int show_unknown;                   /* show ? if unknown files? */
    int show_modified;                  /* show + if local changes? */
    unsigned int timeout;               /* timeout in milliseconds */
    char *vcs;                          /* e.g. "git", "hg" */
} options_t;

...

options_t options = {
    .debug         = 0,
    .format        = format,
    .show_branch   = 0,
    .show_revision = 0,
    .show_unknown  = 0,
    .show_modified = 0,
    .vcs           = NULL
};

...

int opt;
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "hf:dt:v:")) != -1) {
    switch (opt) {
        case 'f':
            options->format = optarg;
            break;
        case 'd':
            options->debug = 1;
            break;
        case 't':
            options->timeout = strtol(optarg, NULL, 10);
            break;
        case 'v':
            printf("%s %s", options->vcs, optarg);
            //options->vcs = optarg;
            break;
    ...
}
```

When I call the program like this `./vcprompt -v foo`, printf puts the following on the output: `(null) git`. If I uncomment the assignment below the printf I get segmentation fault.

What could be the cause of this? It seems to me that what I'm doing with `vcs` is identical to what is being done with `format`. I'm running this in cygwin on 64-bit windows.

#### Edit

This is the definition of format

```
#define DEFAULT_FORMAT "[%n:%b] "
...
char *format = getenv("VCPROMPT_FORMAT");
if (format == NULL)
    format = DEFAULT_FORMAT;
```

Comment: refering to `.format = format ` where is `format` declared and how?

Comment: I think you found a subtle, long-hidden bug in vcprompt! Looks like it 1) only happens when adding a second option that takes a string arg, and 2) depends on the local getopt() implementation. (I could not reproduce your problem on Linux.) Pretty sure that @CyberSpock's answer is correct. Fixed in http://hg.gerg.ca/vcprompt/rev/2f062bc153d6. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "hf:dt:v:")) != -1) {
    switch (opt) {
        case 'f':
            options->format = optarg;
            break;
...
```

to this

```
while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "hf:dt:v:")) != -1) {
    switch (opt) {
        case 'f':
            options->format = strdup(optarg);
            break;

...
```

that way a copy of the option is made and allocate on the heap - same goes for the `vcs` member.

Comment: This indeed did the trick. Thanks. But that still leaves me wondering **why** it was working for `format` (both when passed in as a param and using a default) and not for `vcs`.

Comment: most likely you assigned a local address to format, when that went out of scope you got undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any storage space allocated for `format` or `vcs` to point to. As is, they are *just* pointers.  If you want to have them point to a string, you need space to store the string data itself plus room for a terminator ('\0').  One way to handle it would be to call `strlen()` on the option to get it's length, then use that information so you can use `malloc()` to allocate space large enough to hold the complete C string, then have the pointer in the struct point to that block of memory.